# Basic question on triangulation

Tags: general-topology

As an exercise in Massey, I'm asked:

> For any triangulation of a compact surface, show that $3f=2e$.

But can't we triangulate the closed disk with a single triangle?
The resulting triangulation has 3 vertices, 3 edges, and 1 face, apparently contradicting the theorem.

What am I missing about the definition of a "triangulation"?

Comment: What's a compact surface? What's the definition of a triangulation?

Answer (score 1):

When Massey says Surface he really means Surface without Boundary. In this case every edge must touch exactly 2 faces, and each face has 3 edges so we get the stated formula.